# Question on the definition of dirac delta function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, dirac-delta

I was reading Wikipedia on the Dirac delta function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function and there is a part that says: $\delta$ function is expressed by 
$$
\delta(x) = 1/2 \pi \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{i \alpha x} d \alpha.
$$

I was wondering why this can be interpreted as a delta function, because
to be a delta function $\delta(x)$ has to be $0$ when $x$ is not zero. 
However, given some fixed non-zero $x$,
$$
\lim_{L \rightarrow \infty} 1/2 \pi \int_{- L}^{L} e^{i \alpha x} d \alpha
$$
does not seem to be $0$.

I would greatly appreciate any explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: That representation is not an integral, but rather notation.

Comment: Note: the Dirac delta "function" is *not* a function.

Answer (score 1):

Well it isn't zero because when you compute it, 
$$∫_{-L}^L e^{i\alpha x} \ \text{d}\alpha = \frac{e^{iLx} - e^{iLx}}{ix} = \frac{\sin(Lx)}{2x} = \frac{L}{2} \frac{\sin(Lx)}{Lx}$$
you see that there isn't a limit as $L→∞$. The expression is more subtle than that.

You may want to see the following related question, [Dirac Delta function and normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948336/dirac-delta-function-and-normal-distribution?rq=1) 
Roughly, the Gaussian distribution with variance tending to zero, has the 'pointwise' behaviour one asks of the 'dirac delta function'.

Also, the following PDF may be helpful.
http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~kosta/CompVis_Notes/fourier_transform_Gaussian.pdf